# R: Data frame names with escape characters

Tags: r, escaping, dataframe, names

In R, how can I do this

```
mdf1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(11:15),c=c(21:25),d=c(101:105))
names(mdf1)[2] <- 'A-11:01'
```

in one operation? Something like:

```
mdf1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:5),'A-11:01'=c(11:15),c=c(21:25),d=c(101:105))
```

which produces A.11.01 instead... Thanks!

Comment: You should ask yourself whether you understand problems you are creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame()`.

```
data.frame(a = 1:5, "A-11:01" = 11:15, c = 21:25, check.names = FALSE)
#   a A-11:01  c
# 1 1      11 21
# 2 2      12 22
# 3 3      13 23
# 4 4      14 24
# 5 5      15 25
```

**Note:** You don't need all those `c()` calls around the sequence generation operator `:`

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of check.names!